# Show Iframe after loading content

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I am using an Iframe from an external source and want to show its content just after the page(iframe) has completely loaded. 
I have a div to overlay the page with a message "Please wait" but it is not working properly. The DIV hides before the Iframe has completely loaded. 
 Is there any better way for doing it? ( Browser : IE )

Code :

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("hideAll").style.display = "block"; </script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() 
{ document.getElementById("hideAll").style.display = "none"; } </script> 

<style type="text/css">
body{
overflow: hidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#hideAll
{
position: relative;
left: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
bottom: 0px; 
background-color: white;
z-index: 99; 

}
#main{
width:1600px;
height: 500px;
margin:0 auto;
position: relative;
top: -50px;
left: -400px;
}
#Overlay {
opacity:    1; 
background-color: white; 
width:      227px;
height:     100%; 
z-index:    1;
top:        140px; 
left:       0; 
position: relative;
}


 #Overlay2 {
 opacity:    1; 
 background-color: white; 
 width:      262px;
 height:     100%; 
 z-index:    2;
 top:        140px; 
 left:       765px; 
 position: relative;
}

</style>
</head>

 <body>
<div  id="hideAll"> Please wait...</div>

 <div id="main"> 
<iframe  src="http://ectect.com"  scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin-left:0px;"/></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your code should work as it is. I suppose the `iframe` uses ajax or some other asynchronous technique (or its own `window.onload`), which stretches the "loading" time past `iframe`'s own `window.onload`. In this case, the only way to get a reliable ready message from `iframe`, is to create and send that manually from the `iframe`. If you can't control the file, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I have everything working fine on Chrome with this code. I cannot manage in IE as it worked only few times, not reliable and I need IE because I need to create .hta file and run it from my desktop.. The problem is that HTA default browser is IE. another reason I cannot use chrome is that people using this file don't have it and if I embed a portable version of chrome, I can't use the window.resize() as it does not work function and my template customized...

Comment: But you can control the content of the `iframe`? If so, you can invoke kinda "ready" function on main page from `iframe`, when everything there is finished.

Comment: Btw. If you test your code as a HTA, don't forget to add `application="yes"` attribute in the `iframe` tag, without it you can't get cross-frame access. This maybe blocks `onload` from `iframe` too?. I've never had troubles with `onload` within HTAs, it seems to work also with third party content (though in case of third party content in `iframe`, you _should not_ use application="yes").

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not really using jQuery in your example, even though you're loading it in the `<head>` section. Using jQuery I'd try out something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hideAll").show();
  });

  $("#main iframe").load(function() {
    $("#hideAll").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Use that snippet in the end of the `<body>` instead of the original two at the start of the document.

Comment: Hmm... `$(document).ready()` is executed when `onDOMContentLoaded` fires, OP has `window.onload`, which is supposed to wait untill all resources on the page has been loaded. "`The DIV hides before the Iframe has completely loaded`" is the issue here.

Comment: Ok. Had to test this, and this edited version seems to work as expected - at least on Firefox.