# jQuery $(window).load event called too early on page with iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, iframe

I have a JSF-Page to display another website in an iFrame:

```
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" style="display:none; 
width: 100%; height: 700px" scrolling="yes" />
```

This website needs authorization which I perform with hidden input fields and a form submit with JavaScript. After the login I go to another url.

```
<form id="login" target="frame" method="post" action="LOGIN-URL">
   <input type="hidden" name="username" value="Test"/>
</form>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('login').submit();
   var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
   iframe.onload = function() {
      if (iframe.src.indexOf(REDIRECT-URL) == -1) {
          iframe.src = REDIRECT-URL;
      }
   }                    
</script>
```

During the loading process I want to show a loading icon (contained in a div) and after the REDIRECT-URL finished loading I want to display the iFrame. So as you can see the iFrame is initially not displayed. After complete pageload I want to invoke a function to set another style class for the iFrame (and the loading div).

```
function changeStyle() {
   document.getElementById("frame").className = "show";
   document.getElementById("loading").className = "hide";
}
```

---

```
<script>
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
      changeStyle();
   });
</script>
```

Login and navigation to the redirect url works fine, but with Chrome and Safari (Firefox works fine, didn't try other browsers) the function "changeStyle" is called directly after the login in the iFrame. So the iFrame gets displayed to early. Problem is that the redirected url takes quite some time to load and so user sees the login-landing-page too long and tries to go from here. 
So how can I achieve (window).load being called after the redirect?

Already tried with

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
}, false);
```

and

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', yourFunctionName);
} else {
    if(window.onload) {
        var curronload = window.onload;
        var newonload = function() {
            curronload();
            yourFunctionName();
        };
        window.onload = newonload;
    } else {
        window.onload = yourFunctionName;
    }
}
```

similar questions:

[Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load?rq=1)

[Show Iframe after loading content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858222/show-iframe-after-loading-content)

[call a function after complete page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/call-a-function-after-complete-page-load)

Comment: Is the "other" website in the same domain?

Comment: No, the other website is an external page.